# How to use #selector in Swift 2.2 for the first responder, without a class?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, selector

I want to send `doSomething` to the `firstResponder`, which could be any of several objects.

```
menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Do Something!",
                      action: Selector("doSomething"),
                      keyEquivalent: "")
```

I was using `Selector("doSomething")` prior to Swift 2.2. How do I do it now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a protocol with the Selector `doSomething` and have all of your objects that can be first responders conform to it.  Then implement the selector for your classes.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func myCoolFuncThatManyObjectsRespondTo()
}

extension NSObject: MyProtocol {
    func myCoolFuncThatManyObjectsRespondTo() {
        print("Sup?")
    }
}

let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Do Something!", action: #selector(MyProtocol.myCoolFuncThatManyObjectsRespondTo), keyEquivalent: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#selector({classname}.{methodname}{signature})

func doSomething() {}

  #selector(MyClass.doSomething)

func doSomething(arg: String) {}

  #selector(MyClass.doSomething(_:))

func doSomething(arg: String, withSomething something: Int) {}

  #selector(MyClass.doSomething(_:withSomething:))
```

Note that the selected method must be bridged to Objective-C, so either `MyClass` should extend `NSObject` or add `@objc` annotation to the method.