# Swift macOS SegmentedControl Action not getting called

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, action, nssegmentedcontrol

**Description**

I am trying to use `NSSegmentedControls` to transition between Child ViewControllers. The `ParentViewController` is located in `Main.storyboard` and the `ChildViewControllers` are located in `Assistant.storyboard`. Each ChildViewController has a SegmentedControl divided into 2 Segments and their primary use is to navigate between the ChildViewControllers. So they are set up as `momentaryPushIn` rather than selectOne. Each ChildViewController uses a *Delegate* to communicate with the ParentViewController.

So in the ParentViewController I added the ChildViewControllers as following:

```
/// The View of the ParentViewController configured as NSVisualEffectView
@IBOutlet var visualEffectView: NSVisualEffectView!

var assistantChilds: [NSViewController] {
    get { return [NSViewController]() }
    set(newValue) {
        for child in newValue { self.addChild(child) }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    addAssistantViewControllersToChildrenArray()
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
    visualEffectView.addSubview(self.children[0].view)
    self.children[0].view.frame = self.view.bounds
}

private func addAssistantViewControllersToChildrenArray() -> Void {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Assistant", bundle: nil)
    let exampleChild = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ExampleChild") as! ExampleChildViewController
    let exampleSibling = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ExampleSibling") as! ExampleSiblingViewController

    exampleChild.navigationDelegate = self
    exampleSibling.navigationDelegate = self

    assistantChilds = [exampleChild, exampleSibling]
}
```

So far so good. The `ExampleChildViewController` has an `NSTextField` instance. While I am in the scope of the TextField, I can trigger the action of the SegmentedControls. Its navigating forward and backward as it should. But once I leave the scope of the TextField I can still click the Segments, but they are not triggering any action. They should be able to navigate forward and backward even if the TextField is not the current "First Responder" of the application. I think I am missing something out here, I hope anyone can help me with this. I know the problem is not the `NSSegmentedControl` because I am seeing the same behavior with an `NSButton`, which is configured as Switch/Checkbox, in the SiblingViewController. I just don't have any idea anymore what I am doing wrong.

*It`s my first time asking a question myself here, so I hope the way I am doing is fine for making progress with the solution. Let me know if I can do something better/different or if I need to provide more information about something.*

Thanks in advance!

---

> **Additional Information**
>
> For the sake of completeness:
>
> The `ParentViewController` itself is embedded in a `ContainerView`,
>   which is owned by the `RootViewController`. I can't imagine this does
>   matter in any way, but this way we are not missing something out.
>
> ---
>
> I am actually not showing the navigation action, because I want to
>   keep it as simple as possible. Furthermore the action is not problem,
>   it does what I want it to do. Correct me if I am wrong with this.

---

*Possible solutions I found while researching,* which did not work for me:

- [Setting window.delegate of the ChildViewControllers to NSApp.windows.first?.delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914650/how-to-make-embedded-view-controller-part-of-the-responder-chain)
- [Setting the ChildViewController to `becomeFirstResponder` in its `func viewWillAppear()`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-bring-a-subview-to-the-front-of-a-uiview)
- [`visualEffectView.addSubview(self.children[0].view, positioned: NSWindow.OrderingMode.above, relativeTo: nil`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872840/how-do-i-make-an-nsview-move-to-the-front-of-all-nsviews)

---

Related problems/topics I found while researching:

- [Basic segmented control not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257746/basic-segmented-control-not-working)
- [Adding and Removing Child View Controllers](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-and-Removing-Child-View-Controllers)
- [NSSegmentedControl - Odd appearance when placed in blur view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609653/nssegmentedcontrol-odd-appearance-when-placed-in-blur-view)
- [How to set first responder to NSTextView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727846/how-to-set-first-responder-for-nstextview-in-swift)
- [How to use #selector in Swift 2.2 for the first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319623/how-to-use-selector-in-swift-2-2-for-the-first-responder-without-a-class)
- [Accessing methods, actions and/or outlets from other controllers with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027817/accessing-methods-actions-and-or-outlets-from-other-controllers-with-swift)
- [How to use Child View Controllers in Swift 4.0 programmatically](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/7w34m5/how_to_use_child_view_controllers_in_swift_40/)
- [Container View Controllers](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/)
- [issues with container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852441/issues-with-container-view)
- [Control a NSTabViewController from parent View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005622/control-a-nstabviewcontroller-from-parent-view/37012322#37012322)
- [How to detect when NSTextField has the focus or is it`s content selected cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692122/how-to-detect-when-nstextfield-has-the-focus-or-is-its-content-selected-cocoa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
let parentViewControllerInstance = self.parent as! ParentViewController
segmentedControl.target = parentViewControllerInstance
```

In my case I just had to set the delegate as the target of the `sendAction` method.

---

**Background**

Ok, after hours of reading the AppKit Documentation I am now able to answer my own question.

First, debugging the UI showed that the problem was definitely not in the ViewHierarchy.[image: Debugging UI]

So I tried to think about the nature of NSButton and NSSegmentedControl. At some point I noticed that both are subclasses of NSControl.

```
class NSSegmentedControl : NSControl
class NSButton : NSControl
```

The AppKit Documentation says:

> Discussion
>
> Buttons are a standard control used to initiate actions within your app. You can configure buttons with many different visual styles, but the behavior is the same. **When clicked, a button calls the action method of its associated target object**. (...) You use the action method to perform your app-specific tasks.

The bold text points to the key of the solution – *of its associated target object*. Typically I define the action of an control item like this:

```
button.action = #selector(someFunc(_:))
```

This causes the NSControl instance to call this:

```
func sendAction(_ action: Selector?, to target: Any?) -> Bool
```

Parameter Description from the documentation:

> *Parameters*
>
> > **theAction**
> >
> > The selector to invoke on the target. If the selector is NULL, no message is sent.
> >
> > **theTarget**
> >
> > The target object to *receive the message*. **If the object is nil, the application searches the responder chain for an object capable of handling the message**. For more information on dispatching actions, see the class description for NSActionCell.

In conclusion the NSControl instance, which was firing the action method (in my case the NSSegmentedControl), had no target to send its action to. So it was only able to send its action method across the responder chain - which obviously has been nil while the first responder was located in another view.